# How to use custom file instead of log4j.properties

Tags: java, log4j

I'm using log4j in my java project. Instead of log4j.properties, i want to configure another file... Can anyone help me... Thanks in advance..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875663/log4j-properties-in-a-custom-place

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```java
org.apache.log4j.LogManager.resetConfiguration( );
if ( System.getProperty( "log4j.config" ) != null ) {
    DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch( System.getProperty( "log4j.config" ) );
}
else {
    DOMConfigurator.configure( Loader.getResource( "log4j.properties" ) );
}
```

Use this one time; you only have to specify the path to your log4j file via system paramaters:

```
-Dlog4j.config=/path/to/your/log4j.properties
```

Comment: You are welcome; could you please upvote my answer or even set the "solved hook" if it helped? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This is a [FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#sysprops).

Just use java -Dlog4j.configuration=your/file/path.properties. See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit for details about this system property.

Comment: Property value should be a valid URL. The correct way is:
`-Dlog4j.configuration=file:your/file/path.properties`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("configFilename")
```