# log4j properties file cannot be read

Tags: java, log4j

I am having a problem while using 'log4j'.

> Problem is, its properties file cannot be read unless it is named 'log4j.properties' but all I need is to name it as 'myproject.properties'.

Comment: Why do you *need* to name it `myproject.properties`? These different systems are usually configured in their own files, and logging particularly so, since it's common for the end-user to want to customize the logging parameters.

Comment: Simply I need to check that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this post ([How to use custom file instead of log4j.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595025/how-to-use-custom-file-instead-of-log4j-properties)) should solve your problem.  basically, you pass a **log4j.config** system property.