# Cannot find log file in my project logs folder in spring mvc project

Tags: java, log4j, logfile

I use log4j in my spring mvc project and I create log file uing log4j.properties in the following.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger= INFO, info, file, stdout, error

# Direct log messages to a log file [INFO]
log4j.appender.info=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.info.File=.logs\\mylog.log
log4j.appender.info.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.info.MaxFileSize=1Kb
log4j.appender.info.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.info.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.info.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.info.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I want it to be stored in myapp/logs folder in my web application . what part i should for the file.

here is the directory [image]

Comment: irrelevant tag removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now it will be saved in the current working directory of your IDE (Eclipse or STS, I guess). Its not a good idea to put the file in the project structure, because that structure wont exist, once you deployed the app anywhere.

In Spring you can define a property in youe web.xml, to make the location variable:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
  <param-value>mywebapp.root</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then add a variable to your config:

```
log4j.appender.info.File=${mywebapp.root}/logs/mylog.log
```

If you have to store it in the application, you can also define that [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965946/configuring-log4j-loggers-programmatically), by makeing use of "[ServletContext.getRealPath(".")](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) to find out where your app is deployed, and then set the path to the file.

Comment: I follow you but there still not file in folder logs

Comment: The file will be placed in the logs directory, in your project, on the server, where you deployed your app. I.e. if you are using Tomcat, have a look in the webapps directory. If you want the file to appear in your Eclipse project folder, you will have to set an absolute path.

Comment: can you tell me how to put absolute path??

Comment: Sure just adjust this line: log4j.appender.info.File=C:/[PATH_TO_PROJECT_FOLDER]/logs/mylog.log

Comment: are there anyway beside put the absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

In the normal scenario web-app checks for your log file at the root of your class path. To load a file from custom location , have a look at below posts

[Change location of log4j.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390521/change-location-of-log4j-properties)

[How to use custom file instead of log4j.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595025/how-to-use-custom-file-instead-of-log4j-properties)

EDIT :

From op's comment to generate your log file in the projects path , where you have placed your logs directory . you can simply specify it as ,

```
log4j.appender.file.File= logs/mylog.log
```

Comment: no you are confusing my question. I want to know what path should i put in properties file  in order to store log file that record all log folder logs that I red cirecle in the picture

Comment: Oh i am sorry , do you want to put your log file inside the logs folder , if i understand it correctly ?

Comment: I put this but the log was store in eclipse director not in logs folders in my project